# JavaScript native groupBy reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

I am using JavaScript native reduce, however I want to slightly change in the grouping to get my desired result. 
I have an array as follows:

```
const people = [
  {name: "John", age: 23, city: "Seattle", state: "WA"},
  {name: "Mark", age: 25, city: "Houston", state: "TX"},
  {name: "Luke", age: 26, city: "Seattle", state: "WA"},
  {name: "Paul", age: 28, city: "Portland", state: "OR"},
  {name: "Matt", age: 21, city: "Oakland", state: "CA"},
  {name: "Sam", age: 24, city: "Oakland", state: "CA"}
]
```

I want to group it and change it to this:

```
const arranged = [
  {
    city: "Seattle",
    state: "WA",
    persons: [
      { name: "John", age: 23 },
      {name: "Luke", age: 26}
    ]
  },
    {
    city: "Houston",
    state: "TX",
    persons: [
      {name: "Mark", age: 25}
    ]
  },
  {
    city: "Portland",
    state: "OR",
    persons : [
      {name: "Paul", age: 28}
    ]
  },
  {
    city: "Oakland",
    state: "CA",
    persons: [
      {name: "Matt", age: 21},
      {name: "Sam", age: 24}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: please add your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to group and build the desired output.

```js
const people = [  {name: "John", age: 23, city: "Seattle", state: "WA"},  {name: "Mark", age: 25, city: "Houston", state: "TX"},  {name: "Luke", age: 26, city: "Seattle", state: "WA"},  {name: "Paul", age: 28, city: "Portland", state: "OR"},  {name: "Matt", age: 21, city: "Oakland", state: "CA"},  {name: "Sam", age: 24, city: "Oakland", state: "CA"}]

const result = Object.values(people.reduce((a, {name, age, city, state}) => {
  var key = [city, state].join('|');
  (a[key] || (a[key] = {city, state, persons: []})).persons.push({name, age});
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: More than half the states in the US have a city named (eg) [Oakland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakland_(disambiguation)) - your conditional should match city *and* state!

Comment: @naomik interesting!

Comment: is there a way I can completely abstract this method. I have made an attempt, but it didn't work..
function structuringData(rawData, allFields, matchingKey, parentObject, groupedArray, childObject ){
    const result = Object.values(rawData.reduce((a, {allFields}) => {
        (a[matchingCondition] || (a[matchingCondition] = {parentObject, groupedArray: []}))[groupedArray].push({groupedObject});
        return a;
      }, {}));
    return result;

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and a stringified object as key for grouping.

Later render the wanted array with objects of the keys and the grouped persons.

```js
var people = [{ name: "John", age: 23, city: "Seattle", state: "WA" }, { name: "Mark", age: 25, city: "Houston", state: "TX" }, { name: "Luke", age: 26, city: "Seattle", state: "WA" }, { name: "Paul", age: 28, city: "Portland", state: "OR" }, { name: "Matt", age: 21, city: "Oakland", state: "CA" }, { name: "Sam", age: 24, city: "Oakland", state: "CA" }],
    arranged = Array.from(
        people.reduce((m, o) => {
            var key = JSON.stringify(Object.assign(...['city', 'state'].map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));
            return m.set(key, (m.get(key) || []).concat({ name: o.name, age: o.age }));
        }, new Map),
        ([key, persons]) => Object.assign(JSON.parse(key), { persons })
    );

console.log(arranged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is very nice; i think you will like how my answer avoids the `JSON` conversion :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I use **[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** and **[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)**

```js
const people = [
  {name: "John", age: 23, city: "Seattle", state: "WA"},
  {name: "Mark", age: 25, city: "Houston", state: "TX"},
  {name: "Luke", age: 26, city: "Seattle", state: "WA"},
  {name: "Paul", age: 28, city: "Portland", state: "OR"},
  {name: "Matt", age: 21, city: "Oakland", state: "CA"},
  {name: "Sam", age: 24, city: "Oakland", state: "CA"}
];
var arranged=[];
people.forEach(function(e){
    var exist=false;
    arranged.forEach(function(e1){
        if(e1.state===e.state){
            exist=true;
            e1.persons.push({name:e.name,age:e.age});
        }
    });
    if(!exist){
        arranged.push({state:e.state,city:e.city,persons:[{name:e.name,age:e.age}]}); 
     }
});
console.log(arranged);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial problem. You first have to define *what* constitutes a grouping, and you also have to define *how* like terms will be combined. You problem is exacerbated by the need to group by a *non-primitive* value: city *and* state. Ie, we can't just group based on `city` alone; [more than half the states in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakland_(disambiguation)) have a city named Oakland. Other answers solve this by serializing the city and state in a string, but I will show you a more generic solution that works for compound data of any type.

This is tagged with functional programming, so I'll start with a module for separating our subtasks

```
const DeepMap =
  { has: (map, [ k, ...ks ]) =>
      ks.length === 0
        ? map.has (k)
        : map.has (k)
          ? DeepMap.has (map.get (k), ks)
          : false

  , set: (map, [ k, ...ks ], value) =>
      ks.length === 0
        ? map.set (k, value)
        : map.has (k)
            ? (DeepMap.set (map.get (k), ks, value), map)
            : map.set (k, DeepMap.set (new Map, ks, value))

  , get: (map, [ k, ...ks ]) =>
      ks.length === 0
        ? map.get (k)
        : map.has (k)
          ? DeepMap.get (map.get (k), ks)
          : undefined
  }
```

Now we can define our  generic `groupBy` function

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const { has, set, get } =
  DeepMap

const groupBy = (key = identity, value = identity, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce 
    ((m, x) =>
      has (m, key (x))
        ? set ( m
              , key (x)
              , [ ...get (m, key (x)), value (x) ]
              )
        : set ( m
              , key (x)
              , [ value (x) ]
              )
    , new Map
    )
```

We use `groupBy` by specifying a `key` and `value` functions – The *key* function specifies what an item is grouped by, and the *value* functions specifies the value to be added to the group

```
const people =
  [ { name: "John", age: 23, city: "Seattle", state: "WA" }
  , { name: "Mark", age: 25, city: "Houston", state: "TX" }
  , { name: "Luke", age: 26, city: "Seattle", state: "WA" }
  , { name: "Paul", age: 28, city: "Portland", state: "OR" }
  , { name: "Matt", age: 21, city: "Oakland", state: "CA" }
  , { name: "Sam", age: 24, city: "Oakland", state: "CA" }
  ]

const res =
  groupBy ( k => [ k.state, k.city ]
          , v => ({ name: v.name, age: v.age })
          , people
          )

console.log (res.get ('WA'))
// Map { 'Seattle' => [ { name: 'John', age: 23 }, { name: 'Luke', age: 26 } ] }

console.log (res.get ('WA') .get ('Seattle'))
// [ { name: 'John', age: 23 }, { name: 'Luke', age: 26 } ]
```

We can see how this intermediate result would be useful. It provides incredibly efficient lookup thanks to `Map`. Of course you'll want to iterate thru the deep map in more meaningful ways though. Let's add an `entries` procedure to our module

```
const DeepMap =
  { ...
  , entries: function* (map, fields = [])
      {
        const loop = function* (m, path, [ f, ...fields ])
        {
          if (fields.length === 0)
            for (const [ key, value ] of m)
              yield [ { ...path, [ f ]: key }, value ]
          else
            for (const [ key, value ] of m)
              yield* loop (value, { ...path, [ f ]: key }, fields)

        }
        yield* loop (map, {}, fields)
      }
  }


for (const [ key, value ] of DeepMap.entries (res, [ 'state', 'city' ]))
  console.log (key, value)

// { state: 'WA', city: 'Seattle' } [ { name: 'John', age: 23 }, { name: 'Luke', age: 26 } ]
// { state: 'TX', city: 'Houston' } [ { name: 'Mark', age: 25 } ]
// { state: 'OR', city: 'Portland' } [ { name: 'Paul', age: 28 } ]
// { state: 'CA', city: 'Oakland' } [ { name: 'Matt', age: 21 }, { name: 'Sam', age: 24 } ]
```

Now that our deep map is iterable, we can easily produce your desired output using `Array.from`

```
const arranged = 
  Array.from ( entries (res, [ 'state', 'city' ])
             , ([ key, persons ]) => ({ ...key, persons })
             )

console.log (arranged)
// [
//   {
//     city: "Seattle",
//     state: "WA",
//     persons: [
//       { name: "John", age: 23 },
//       { name: "Luke", age: 26 }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     city: "Houston",
//     state: "TX",
//     persons: [
//       { name: "Mark", age: 25 }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     city: "Portland",
//     state: "OR",
//     persons : [
//       { name: "Paul", age: 28 }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     city: "Oakland",
//     state: "CA",
//     persons: [
//       { name: "Matt", age: 21 },
//       { name: "Sam", age: 24 }
//     ]
//   }
// ]
```

Program demonstration

```js
const DeepMap =
  { has: (map, [ k, ...ks ]) =>
      ks.length === 0
        ? map.has (k)
        : map.has (k)
          ? DeepMap.has (map.get (k), ks)
          : false

  , set: (map, [ k, ...ks ], value) =>
      ks.length === 0
        ? map.set (k, value)
        : map.has (k)
            ? (DeepMap.set (map.get (k), ks, value), map)
            : map.set (k, DeepMap.set (new Map, ks, value))
        
  , get: (map, [ k, ...ks ]) =>
      ks.length === 0
        ? map.get (k)
        : map.has (k)
          ? DeepMap.get (map.get (k), ks)
          : undefined
          
  , entries: function* (map, fields = [])
      {
        const loop = function* (m, path, [ f, ...fields ])
        {
          if (fields.length === 0)
            for (const [ key, value ] of m)
              yield [ { ...path, [ f ]: key }, value ]
          else
            for (const [ key, value ] of m)
              yield* loop (value, { ...path, [ f ]: key }, fields)
        }
        yield* loop (map, {}, fields)
      }
  }

const identity = x =>
  x
  
const { has, set, get, entries } =
  DeepMap

const groupBy = (key = identity, value = identity, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce 
    ((m, x) =>
      has (m, key (x))
        ? set ( m
              , key (x)
              , [ ...get (m, key (x)), value (x) ]
              )
        : set ( m
              , key (x)
              , [ value (x) ]
              )
    , new Map
    )
    
const people =
  [ { name: "John", age: 23, city: "Seattle", state: "WA" }
  , { name: "Mark", age: 25, city: "Houston", state: "TX" }
  , { name: "Luke", age: 26, city: "Seattle", state: "WA" }
  , { name: "Paul", age: 28, city: "Portland", state: "OR" }
  , { name: "Matt", age: 21, city: "Oakland", state: "CA" }
  , { name: "Sam", age: 24, city: "Oakland", state: "CA" }
  ]
  
const res =
  groupBy ( k => [ k.state, k.city ]
          , v => ({ name: v.name, age: v.age })
          , people
          )
          
for (const [ key, value ] of entries (res, [ 'state', 'city' ]))
  console.log (key, value)

// { state: 'WA', city: 'Seattle' } [ { name: 'John', age: 23 }, { name: 'Luke', age: 26 } ]
// { state: 'TX', city: 'Houston' } [ { name: 'Mark', age: 25 } ]
// { state: 'OR', city: 'Portland' } [ { name: 'Paul', age: 28 } ]
// { state: 'CA', city: 'Oakland' } [ { name: 'Matt', age: 21 }, { name: 'Sam', age: 24 } ]
  
const arranged = 
  Array.from ( entries (res, [ 'state', 'city '])
             , ([ key, persons ]) => ({ ...key, persons })
             )
             
console.log ('arranged', arranged)
// arranged [
//   {
//     city: "Seattle",
//     state: "WA",
//     persons: [
//       { name: "John", age: 23 },
//       { name: "Luke", age: 26 }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     city: "Houston",
//     state: "TX",
//     persons: [
//       { name: "Mark", age: 25 }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     city: "Portland",
//     state: "OR",
//     persons : [
//       { name: "Paul", age: 28 }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     city: "Oakland",
//     state: "CA",
//     persons: [
//       { name: "Matt", age: 21 },
//       { name: "Sam", age: 24 }
//     ]
//   }
// ]
```

Comment: I wish I had more time for this answer specifically. If this interests you, I solve this similar problem other ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129575/633183) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244545/633183)

Answer (score 0):

I have built a generic group by reducer, you pass it the keys by which you want to group and it gives you a custom reducer function. This reducer gives you an object indexed by a (composed or simple) key containing an array of items that share this key. You can reuse it to have it grouped by the key(s) you want to.

Here are two examples.

```js
const people = Object.freeze([{
  name: "John",
  age: 23,
  city: "Seattle",
  state: "WA"
}, {
  name: "Mark",
  age: 25,
  city: "Houston",
  state: "TX"
}, {
  name: "Luke",
  age: 26,
  city: "Seattle",
  state: "WA"
}, {
  name: "Paul",
  age: 28,
  city: "Portland",
  state: "OR"
}, {
  name: "Matt",
  age: 21,
  city: "Oakland",
  state: "CA"
}, {
  name: "Sam",
  age: 24,
  city: "Oakland",
  state: "CA"
}]);

const groupByReducer = (group) =>
  (result, row) => {

    const keygroup = group.map((v) => row[v]);
    const key = keygroup.join(':');

    if (result[key])
      result[key].push(row);
    else
      result[key] = [row];

    return result;

  };

const byCityState = people.reduce(
  groupByReducer(['city', 'state']), {});
const byState = people.reduce(groupByReducer(['state']), {});

console.log(byCityState);
console.log(byState);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```