# Javascript Function to flatten multiple input arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, functional-programming

I am dealing with a couple of arrays of objects which will get rendered into the UI using React. So here's the context of what I am doing. I get different data sets from different APIs. These datasets are arrays of arrays of objects. E.g

```
[
 [{age: 23, name: john}],
 [{age: 24, name: jane}],
 [{age: 25, name: sam}],
 [{age: 26, name: smith}],
]
```

With this format, it will be hard to render the result in the UI. So a simple fix will be to flatten the array which returns a single array of objects which then I can map through and display the data on the UI. Now, I have this kind of operation for each of the datasets returned from the API.

- First, I flatten each array of arrays, using `array.flat()`
- Second, I filter duplicated items using `array.filter()`
- Third, I sort these items using `array.sort()`
- Fourth, I merge the arrays together using `array.concat()`
- Fifth, I map through the final array produced from the 4 previous steps.

Following this style I listed above seems to be imperative to me, I wanted to use a more functional approach where I can `pipe` functions together, which will make it more declarative rather than imperative. Currently, I am stuck on writing a function that will accept arrays as inputs, then flatten the arrays into a single final array. Now I know I can flatten an array using the `reduce()` method and. I came across a solution on StackOverflow which looks like this and can be seen from this link [Flatten Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/13850427)

```
const flatten = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => {
        return flat.concat(
            Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten
        )
    }, [])
}
```

I was thinking maybe I could spread the input `arr` parameter but that seems to throw this error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I would appreciate it if I could be guided in the right way and also shown an efficient way to achieve all these operations I listed out. Thank you

Comment: "With this format, it will be hard to render the result in the UI" why? That looks incredibly easy to use in any templating context? Use `data.flat()` and then map the content: ```data.flat().map(e => `<p><em>${e.name}</em> is ${e.age} years old</p>`);``` etc? And if you need sorting, remember to pass a sorting function to `sort()` so that you can sort on name or age or any other object property you need.

Comment: i would like to help you achieve the other goals you mentioned but your post needs a bit of clarification. what constitutes a duplicate? object with the same `name` property? could you specify a concrete array of inputs and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should do what you're looking for. It would help to have a few samples of different return data to merge together, but I tried to reproduce what you explained in my solution below.

First I combine all the different source arrays into one single array and then flatten that to any depth any of the source arrays have. In case this depth is variable, I used `flat(Infinity)` but you could use a finite depth as well (`flat(2)` or `flat(3)`). Once I've flattened the array, I briefly convert it to a `Set` to remove any duplicates and then convert it back to an array.

```js
const source1 = [
  [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
  [{age: 24, name: 'jane'}],
  [{age: 25, name: 'sam'}],
  [{age: 26, name: 'smith'}]
];

const source2 = [
  [{age: 27, name: 'mike'}],
  [{age: 28, name: 'joanne'}],
  [{age: 29, name: 'lois'}],
  [{age: 30, name: 'paul'}]
];

const allSources = [...new Set([source1,source2].flat(Infinity))];

console.log(allSources);
```

** Important note here: Because arrays and objects are reference types, even if two source arrays have the same object by key-value pairs, it won't actually be seen as a duplicate. In order to truly filter out any duplicate objects, you'll need to loop through the keys for both objects and compare their associated values, like this:

```js
const source1 = [
  [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
  [{age: 24, name: 'jane'}],
  [{age: 25, name: 'sam'}],
  [{age: 26, name: 'smith'}]
];

const source2 = [
  [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
  [{age: 24, name: 'jane'}],
  [{age: 25, name: 'sam'}],
  [{age: 26, name: 'smith'}],
  [{age: 27, name: 'mike'}],
  [{age: 28, name: 'joanne'}],
  [{age: 29, name: 'lois'}],
  [{age: 30, name: 'paul'}]
];

const allSources = [source1,source2].flat(Infinity).filter((obj,_,a) => a.find(o => Object.keys(obj).length === Object.keys(o).length && Object.keys(obj).every(objKey => Object.keys(o).includes(objKey) && obj[objKey] === o[objKey])) === obj);

console.log(allSources);
```

Comment: or just don't specify the depth, `[source1,source2].flat()`, which is the same as `source1.concat(source2)`. or keep style consistent with your array spread, `[...new Set([...source1, ...source2])]`. as for the second half of your answer, linear `every` inside linear `find` inside linear `filter` is very inefficient. if the input is large or the ui needs to redraw often, this could be a problem. see ori's answer to dramatically reduce the computational complexity.

Comment: Sorry to hear you weren’t a fan of my solution, @ThankYou. It performs very well, even when benchmarked against the other solutions to this question. In fact, the other solution you commented on used very similar practices to my own here. However, the logic that solution uses to determines  duplicate entries differs from my mine and actually achieves a different purpose. Thanks for the advise though. Happy coding!

Comment: @ThankYou I just admit Ori’s solution is much more concise. As soon as I’m back at my computer tonight, I’ll give it a more thorough look. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks for taking the feedback constructively. i wouldn't go so far to say "i'm not a fan," i only wanted to point out that even "correct" programs like yours can have hidden issues that rear their heads under different circumstances. All the best :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.flat()` to flatten multiple levels of arrays. The default is 1, but you can use `Array.flat(Infinity)` to flatten multiple levels.

```js
const arr = [[{"age":23,"name":"john"}],[{"age":24,"name":"jane"}],[{"age":25,"name":"sam"}],[{"age":26,"name":"smith"}]]

const result = arr.flat()

console.log(result)
```

To remove the duplicates, you can now reduce the flattened array to a Map, and then convert it back to an array using the `Map.values()` iterator ad `Array.from()`:

```js
const arr = [[{"age":23,"name":"john"}],[{"age":24,"name":"jane"}],[{"age":25,"name":"sam"}],[{"age":26,"name":"smith"}], [{"age":33,"name":"john"}]]

const result = Array.from(
  arr.flat()
    .reduce((acc, o) => 
      acc.has(o.name)
        ? acc
        : acc.set(o.name, o)
      , new Map())
    .values()
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial problem and an opportunity to learn about designing data structures. This is a long-format answer that hopes to give you the tools to make these analyses on your own. This post uses Brandon's well-intentioned answer as the basis of contrast. First we need to examine the properties of some of JavaScript's built-in structures.

**performance of array**

We will start with Array. If we have an array, `input`, and a known index, `i`, we can fetch the element in **constant** time, `input[i]`. This means neither the size of `input` nor `i` affect how long it will take to get the answer. This is denoted in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) as *O(1)*. This is true because an array is effectively a pointer to a position in memory, and `i` is an offset. Finding the element is a *constant* computation of `position + i` which is always a simple addition.

```js
const input =
  [ "foo", "bar", "cat", "dog", "hat", "ham" ]

const i =
  4

const result =
  input[i]

console.log(result) // "hat"
```

If however the index is unknown and we wish to find an element by it's value, we must scan the array one element at a time. This is known as **linear** complexity and denoted as *O(n)* because the amount of time/space scales linearly with respect to the size of the input, `n`. With an array of `n = 3` elements, we only have to check up to 3 elements to find a match. With an array of `n = 1000`, we would have to check up to 1,000!

```js
const input =
  [ "foo", "bar", "cat", "dog", "hat", "ham" ]

const query =
  "hat"

const result =
  input.findIndex(v => v == query)

console.log(result) // 4
```

Almost every Array operation scales with the size of the input array. These linear operations include `entries`, `every`, `fill`, `filter`, `find`, `findIndex`, `flat`, `flatMap`, `for..of`, `forEach`,  `from`, `includes`, `indexOf`, `join`, `keys`, `lastIndexOf`, `map`, `reduce`, `reduceRight`, `reverse`, `slice`, `some`, `toString`, and `values`. An important-to-know property of linear operations is that when they are nested, they become **quadratic**, or *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

An easy way to see this is two nested `for` loops, *O(n) * O(n) = O(n*n)*. If `n = 1000`, this could take 1,000,000 computations. This would also apply to other linear operations like `includes` nested inside `filter` -

```js
const input =
  [ "foo", "bar", "cat", "dog", "hat", "ham" ]

const result =
  input.filter(v => v.includes("a")) // <- nested linear operations

console.log(result)
// [ "bar", "cat", "hat", "ham" ]
```

**performance of object**

Next we will look at JavaScript's Objects. Like Arrays, if we have an object, `input`, and a known key, `query`, we can retrieve a value in constant time, *O(1)* -

```js
const input =
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

const query =
  "b"

const result =
  input[b]

console.log(result) // 2
```

Now say we have two objects, `foo` and `bar`, and wish to determine if they are equals. Our function `isEqual` combines `Object.keys`, *O(n)*, with `every`, *O(n)*, and nests `includes`, *O(n)*, with a property lookup, *O(1)*. This is *O(n + n * (n + 1))* which simplifies to *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. The `includes` check here is unnecessary but we following Brandon's example for comparison -

```js
const foo =
  { a: 1, b: 3 }

const bar =
  { b: 3, a: 1 }

const isEqual = (x,y) =>
  Object.keys(x).every(k => y.includes(k) && y[k] === x[k])

console.log(isEqual(foo, bar)) // true
```

**compound performance**

For our final example, let's take an array of objects, `input`, and a `query` object, and try to find the query's index. We already determined `isEqual` is a quadratic, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. When we nest this operation inside linear `findIndex`, we end up with *O(n)* * *O(n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>3</sup>)*. If `n = 1000` this would take 1,000,000,000 computations! As you can see, linear operations can scale in computational complexity very quickly -

```js
const input =
  [ { a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 3 } ]

const query =
  { b: 2, a: 1 }

function isEqual(x, y) {
  return Object.keys(x).every(k => y.includes(k) && y[k] === x[k])
}

const result =
  input.findIndex(v => isEqual(v, query))

console.log(result) // 1
```

Now let's analyze Brandon's answer. I don't want anyone to think I'm picking on him. His program is valid and returns the correct result. However as the input size grows, its process *can* grind your cpu to a halt. If this program were used in a loop or happens every UI refresh, it *could* be a problem.

```js
const allSources =
  [source1,source2]
      .flat(Infinity)
      .filter((obj,_,a) =>
         a.find(o =>
           Object.keys(obj).length === Object.keys(o).length
             && Object.keys(obj).every(objKey =>
               Object.keys(o).includes(objKey)
                 && obj[objKey] === o[objKey])) === obj)
```

| complexity | operation |
| --- | --- |
| *O(1)* | `.length`, `===`, `&&` |
| *O(n)* | `flat`,`filter`,`keys`,`every`,`includes` |

| computational complexity |
| --- |
| *O(n + n * (n * (n + 1 + 1 + n + 1 + n + n * (n + n + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1))))* |
| = *O(n + n * (n * (n + 1 + 1 + n + 1 + n + n * (n))))* |
| = *O(n + n * (n * (n + 1 + 1 + n + 1 + n + n<sup>2</sup>)))* |
| = *O(n + n * (n<sup>3</sup>))* |
| = *O(n<sup>4</sup>)* |

**my first data structure**

Above the `filter(...)` algorithm has *O(n<sup>4</sup>)* complexity. For an input size of `n = 1000`, that is an estimated 1,000,000,000,000 (one trillion) operations! If we want a faster solution, we cannot rely on Array's linear operations, but JavaScript does not include a data type that does exactly what we need. Maybe you never designed your own data structure before, maybe you didn't know that was a possibility, that's okay!

We will now look at Map which has very similar properties to Object. The primary difference is that an object's keys **must** be a string whereas Map can associate *any* key type with any value. And like Array and Object, we can nest Map any amount of levels, if desired. We will use `get` sequenced with `get`, to lookup a nested value in **constant** time. This is denoted as *O(1) + O(1) = O(2)* and simplified to *O(1)* -

```js
const key1 =
  { a: "ay" }      // <- any type for key1

const key2 =
  [ "bee" ]        // <- any type for key2

const someValue =
  Symbol("ess")    // <- any value

const m =
  new Map([[ key1, new Map([[ key2, someValue ]]) ]])

const result =
  m.get(key1).get(key2)

console.log(result === someValue) // true
```

In addition to `get`, Map offers `has` which answers whether our particular map, `m`, *has* a particular key, `k` -

```js
const key1 =
  { a: "ay" }

const m =
  new Map([[ key1, "foo" ]])

console.log(m.has(key1))  // true
console.log(m.has("bar")) // false
```

**recmap**

We can use the high-performance properties of Map to write our own Recursive Map type, `recmap`. Before we dive into the implementation, here's how we want it to work -

```js
import { empty, get, set } from "./recmap.js"

const t = empty()                 // <- empty recmap

set(t, ["a", 1, "b", 2], "hello") // <- set a deep value

const result =
  get(t, ["a", 1, "b", 2])        // <- retrieve a deep value

console.log(result) // "hello"
```

We can visualize `t` above as a recursive sequence of nested Maps -

```js
Map { "a" => Map { 1 => Map { "b" => Map { 2 => "hello" }}}}
```

The user does not need to understand Array, Object, or Map to use it effectively. This is known as **data abstraction** and it's an important property of writing effective data structures. We will build our data type so that the nested structure is automatically managed by our module's operations -

```js
// recmap.js

const empty = () =>
  new Map                         // <- representation of "empty" recmap

const has = (t, [ k, ...ks ]) =>  // <- recursive wrapper around Map.has
  ks.length == 0
    ? t.has(k)
    : t.has(k)
      ? has(t.get(k), ks)
      : false

const set = (t, [ k, ...ks ], v) => // <- recursive wrapper around Map.set
  ks.length == 0
    ? t.set(k, v)
    : t.has(k)
      ? (set(t.get(k), ks, v), t)
      : t.set(k, set(empty(), ks, v))

const get = (t, [ k, ...ks ]) =>    // <- recursive wrapper around Map.get
  ks.length == 0
    ? t.get(k)
    : t.has(k)
      ? get(t.get(k), ks)
      : undefined

export { empty, has, set, get }     // <- public module interface
```

Our `recmap` is [extremely fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894824/633183), able to filter a million values in less than one second. This is great, but there's on small problem: the purpose of this question is to compare objects to one another.

**my second data structure**

Hang in there, we are almost done. We designed `recmap` around Map so that the user doesn't have to concern him/herself with managing a nested structure. We will build `unique` around `recmap` so the user is not concerned with neither nested Maps nor key sequences. Instead we can simply create an `empty` collection and freely `add` as many values as we want -

```js
import { empty, has, add, values } from "./unique.js"

const t = empty()             // <- empty unique

add(t, { a:1, b:2, c:3 })     // <- any object

const result =
  has(t, { a:1, b:2, c:3 })   // <- has any object?

console.log(result) // true
```

It doesn't matter which order the input object's keys are in. We will always get the correct answer -

```js
console.log(has(t, { b:2, c:3, a:1 })) // true
```

It doesn't matter if we try to `add` the same object with different key orderings. It will only be added once -

```js
add(t, { b:2, c:3, a:1 })
add(t, { b:2, a:1, c:3 })
add(t, { c:3, a:1, b:2 })

console.log(Array.from(values(t)))
```

```js
[ { c:3, a:1, b:2 } ]   // <- only one distinct object is added
```

**unique**

This module is much easier to write thanks to our existing `recmap`. It is a simple wrapper around `recmap.set` and `recmap.has` with the addition of a `toKey` function which takes care of sequencing the input object. This technique of building complex data structures out of simpler ones is one every functional programmer must master -

```js
// unique.js

import * as recmap from "./recmap.js"

const add = (t, v) =>         // <- wrapper around recmap.set
  recmap.set(t, toKey(v), v)

const has = (t, v) =>         // <- wrapper around recmap.has
  recmap.has(t, toKey(v))

const toKey = v =>            // <- private helper, sequences an object
  Object
    .entries(v)
    .sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
    .flat()

const empty =
  recmap.empty   // <- same empty representation as recmap

const values =
  recmap.values  // <- todo

export { add, empty, has, values } // <- public interface
```

Above notice we did not export `toKey`. This is a **private** function only used by our module; an implementation detail the user does not need to worry about. Also note we called `recmap.values` into existence, we will implement that now -

```js
// recmap.js (continued)

const empty = //...
const has = //...
const set = //...
const get = //...

function* values (t)
{ if (t instanceof Map)
    for (const v of t.values())
      yield *values(v)
  else
    yield t.unwrap
}

export
  { empty, has, set, get, values } // <- update export
```

**benchmark**

We've come along way. It's now time to measure the difference between our `unique` data structure and the linear `filter` algorithm proposed in Brandon's answer. To compare the two, we will use `randCoord` which generates random `{ x, y }` objects -

```js
// fixtures
const rand = x =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * x)

const randCoord = size =>
  ({ x: rand(size), y: rand(size) })

const input =
  Array.from(Array(count), _ => randCoord(size))
```

The `unique` algorithm iterates through the `input` and `add`s each element to our collection -

```js
console.time("unique")
const a = empty()
for (const x of input)
  add(a, x)
console.timeEnd("unique")
console.log(`uniques: ${Array.from(values(a)).length}`)
```

The `filter` algorithm is a polyadic chain of `filter` -> `find` -> `every` -> `includes`, as described above -

```js
console.time("filter")
const b = filter(input)
console.timeEnd("filter")
console.log(`uniques: ${b.length}`)
```

With a size of `randCoord(10)`, we generate coordinates from `(0,0)` to `(10,10)` with a maximum possibility of *10 x 10 = 100* unique coordinates -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 64 | `filter` | 2.26 | 0.023 |
| 1,000 | 100 | `filter` | 11.30 | 0.011 |
| 10,000 | 100 | `filter` | 96.73 | 0.010 |
| 100,000 | 100 | `filter` | 802.52 | 0.008 |

In this case, the linear `filter` algorith never has to check more than 100 elements to determine if one is unique. So even with a high count of 100,000 elements, duplicates can be detected somewhat easily. The `unique` data structure however detects duplicates faster -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 64 | `unique` | 9.68 | 0.097 |
| 1,000 | 100 | `unique` | 3.88 | 0.004 |
| 10,000 | 100 | `unique` | 12.16 | 0.001 |
| 100,000 | 100 | `unique` | 106.31 | 0.001 |

Your real-world data is using `{ name, age }` objects and the unique combinations is probably much greater than *10 x 10*. Next we'll see how as the possible uniques increases, the performance of `filter` hurts more and more. With a size of `randCoord(100)`, we generate coordinates from `(0,0)` to `(100,100)` with a maximum possibility of *100 x 100 = 10,000* unique coordinates -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 98 | `filter` | 2.52 | 0.025 |
| 1,000 | 946 | `filter` | 48.63 | 0.049 |
| 10,000 | 6,340 | `filter` | 3,105.00 | 0.310 |
| 100,000 | 10,000 | `filter` | 67,460.00 | 0.675 |

Here `filter` starts to rear its head. At a modest 1,000 elements, the runtime is already *4x* greater. At 10,000, we see a *32x* increase. By contrast, `unique` handles the larger input space with effectively no increase in runtime -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 98 | `unique` | 9.76 | 0.098 |
| 1,000 | 946 | `unique` | 4.11 | 0.004 |
| 10,000 | 6,340 | `unique` | 13.10 | 0.001 |
| 100,000 | 10,000 | `unique` | 121.55 | 0.001 |

With a size of `randCoord(1000)`, we generate coordinates from `(0,0)` to `(1000,1000)` with a maximum possibility of *1,000 x 1,000 = 1,000,000* unique coordinates. This is similar to a `{ first, last }` object where there could be 1,000 unique first names and 1,000 unique last names -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | `filter` | 0.39 | 0.004 |
| 1,000 | 999 | `filter` | 38.86 | 0.039 |
| 10,000 | 9,950 | `filter` | 3,710.00 | 0.371 |
| 100,000 | 95,186 | `filter` | 364,549.00 | 3.645 |

The noteworthy pattern we need to point out is that as the number of uniques increases, it takes `filter` longer to find **each** result.  With a large count of 100,000 elements to check, it takes over 6 minutes to complete. Meanwhile `unique` computes the result with no increase in runtime as the number of uniques increases -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | `unique` | 0.12 | 0.001 |
| 1,000 | 999 | `unique` | 0.97 | 0.001 |
| 10,000 | 9,950 | `unique` | 11.04 | 0.001 |
| 100,000 | 95,186 | `unique` | 124.99 | 0.001 |

**real-world example**

Above we compared objects with just two fields. In a final benchmark, let's see how the two algorithms compare when dealing with an object with seven (7) fields `first`, `last`, `age`, `phone`, `gender`, and `email` -

```js
// fixtures
const rand = x =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * x)

const randObj = () => ({
    first: rand(1000),
    last: rand(1000),
    age: rand(100),
    phone: rand(1e10),
    gender: rand(2),
    email: rand(1e20)
})

const input =
  Array.from(Array(count), randObj)
```

This is equal to *1000 x 1000 x 100 x 10,000,000,000 x 2 x 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 = 200,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000*, or *2e38*, possible uniques -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | `filter` | 1.95 | 0.019 |
| 1,000 | 1,000 | `filter` | 53.47 | 0.053 |
| 10,000 | 10,000 | `filter` | 4,435.00 | 0.444 |
| 100,000 | 100,000 | `filter` | 471,622.00 | 4.716 |
| 1,000,000 | 1,000,000 | `filter` | ? | ? |

To no surprise, not a single duplicate found, even in 100,000 objects. This demonstrates the **worst-case scenario** for both algorithms. I threw in a large benchmark of 1,000,000 elements just to stress-test the `unique` algorithm. While it would take `filter` over 12 hours to complete, `unique` determines the result in *less than 5 seconds* -

| count | uniques | algorithm | runtime | each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | `unique` | 11.49 | 0.115 |
| 1,000 | 1,000 | `unique` | 6.55 | 0.007 |
| 10,000 | 10,000 | `unique` | 47.77 | 0.005 |
| 100,000 | 100,000 | `unique` | 404.93 | 0.004 |
| 1,000,000 | 1,000,000 | `unique` | 4,956.00 | 0.005 |

---

**enhancement 1**

A big advantage of writing our own data structures is we can change their behaviour and tune their performance as needed. If we add an object and attempt a lookup of using a subset of that object, we will get a `true` answer -

```js
import { empty, add, has } from "./unique.js"

const t = empty()

add(t, {a: 1, b: 2})

console.log(has(t, {a: 1})) // true ❌
```

If the underlying representation of `t` is -

```js
Map { "a" => Map { 1 => Map { "b" => Map { 2 => ... }}}}
```

That means `has(t, {a: 1})` will find the nested map below, and return `true` -

```js
{ "b" => Map { 2 => ... }}
```

You might think this is a problem with `unique` but the issue exists with `recmap` as well. This is a bug and we can fix it by introducing a simple `checksum` -

```js
// recmap.js (continued)

const checksum = key =>
  [ key.length, ...key ]  // <- prepend sequence with length

const empty = // ...
const _get = // ... originally `get`, now private
const _has = // ... originally `has`, now private
const _set = // ... originally `set`, now private

// new wrappers: checksum the key and call private function
const get = (t, k) => _get(t, checksum(k))
const has = (t, k) => _has(t, checksum(k))
const set = (t, k, v) => _set(t, checksum(k), v)

export // ...
```

No changes are necessary for `unique`. We're back in business -

```js
add(t, {a: 1, b: 2})
console.log(has(t, {a: 1})) // false ✅
console.log(has(t, {a: 1, b: 2})) // true ✅
console.log(has(t, {b: 2, a: 1})) // true ✅
```

**enhancement 2**

Our `recmap` module uses `Map` as the underlying representation but the user doesn't (shouldn't) know that. What happens if the user attempts to insert a `Map` of their own into the mix?Introducing a `wrap` utility, we can allow the user to insert *any* value type and prevent the leak of any implementation details -

```js
// recmap.js (continued)

const checksum = // ...
const empty = // ...
const _get = // ... 
const _has = // ... 
const _set = // ...

const wrap = v =>       // <- wrap utility
  ({ unwrap: v })

const has = // ...
const get = (t, k) => _get(t, checksum(k)).unwrap  // <- unwrap
const set = (t, k, v) => _set(t, checksum(k), wrap(v)) // <- wrap

export // ...
```

**enhancement 3**

We designed `recmap` around native Map which offers a few other useful methods. We can add `entries` and `keys` to offer a more complete implementation -

```js
// recmap.js (continued)

// ...

function* entries (t, path = [])
{ if (t instanceof Map)
    for (const [k, v] of t.entries())
      yield *entries(v, [...path, k])
  else
    yield [path.slice(1), t.unwrap ]
}

function* keys (t, path = [])
{ if (t instanceof Map)
    for (const [k, v] of t.entries())
      yield *keys(v, [...path, k])
  else
    yield path.slice(1)
}

export { ..., entries, keys } // <- update export
```

**demo**

An answer without a functioning demo is incomplete, imo. I've inlined the `recmap` and `unique` modules because we are limited to just one "file" for demonstration. We will borrow the input examples from Brandon's post -

```js
const source1 =
  [ {age: 23, name: 'john'}
  , {age: 24, name: 'jane'}
  , {age: 25, name: 'sam'}
  , {age: 26, name: 'smith'}
  ]

const source2 =
  [ {age: 23, name: 'john'}
  , {age: 24, name: 'jane'}
  , {age: 25, name: 'sam'}
  , {age: 26, name: 'smith'}
  , {age: 27, name: 'mike'}
  , {age: 28, name: 'joanne'}
  , {age: 29, name: 'lois'}
  , {age: 30, name: 'paul'}
  ]
```

```js
const recmap = (_ => {     // recmap module
  const empty = () => new Map
  const checksum = key => [ key.length, ...key ]
  const wrap = v => ({ unwrap: v })
  const _has = (t, [ k, ...ks ]) =>  ks.length == 0 ? t.has(k) : t.has(k) ? _has(t.get(k), ks) : false
  const _set = (t, [ k, ...ks ], v) => ks.length == 0 ? t.set(k, v) : t.has(k) ? (_set(t.get(k), ks, v), t) : t.set(k, _set(empty(), ks, v))
  const _get = (t, [ k, ...ks ]) => ks.length == 0 ? t.get(k) : t.has(k) ? _get(t.get(k), ks) : undefined
  const has = (t, keys) => _has(t, checksum(keys))
  const set = (t, keys, v) => _set(t, checksum(keys), wrap(v))
  const get = (t, keys) => _get(t, checksum(keys))?.unwrap
  function* values (t) { if (t instanceof Map) for (const v of t.values()) yield *values(v); else yield t.unwrap }
  return { empty, get, has, set, values }
})()

const unique = (_ => {     // unique module
  const toKey = v => Object.entries(v).sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0])).flat()
  const add = (t, v) => recmap.set(t, toKey(v), v)
  const has = (t, v) => recmap.has(t, toKey(v))
  const empty = recmap.empty
  const values = recmap.values
  return { add, empty, has, values }
})()

const source1 = [{age: 23, name: 'john'}, {age: 24, name: 'jane'}, {age: 25, name: 'sam'}, {age: 26, name: 'smith'}]
const source2 = [{age: 23, name: 'john'}, {age: 24, name: 'jane'}, {age: 25, name: 'sam'}, {age: 26, name: 'smith'}, {age: 27, name: 'mike'}, {age: 28, name: 'joanne'}, {age: 29, name: 'lois'}, {age: 30, name: 'paul'}]
const result = unique.empty()

for (const x of [...source1, ...source2])
  unique.add(result, x)

console.log(Array.from(unique.values(result)))
```

All duplicates are removed -

```js
[ { age: 23, name: 'john' }
, { age: 24, name: 'jane' }
, { age: 25, name: 'sam' }
, { age: 26, name: 'smith' }
, { age: 27, name: 'mike' }
, { age: 28, name: 'joanne' }
, { age: 29, name: 'lois' }
, { age: 30, name: 'paul' }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Brandon for hosting this learning opportunity. This answer currently exists as a draft. I will be adding a functioning code demo, some benchmark analysis, and two enhancements to `recmap` that make it even more useful. Stay tuned!

Comment: Wow, thanks for this educative post, I knew this was a use-case for data structures, but my foundation is quite weak in DSA and I am willing to improve. Can you recommend a link/video or whatever resource that I could learn from extensively? Once again, I really do appreciate this more than you think!

Comment: I'm happy to help :D I updated the post with some notes on the benchmarks as well as some improvements to the introduced data structures. I can recommend nothing more highly than [_Structure and Interpretation of Computer Porgrams_](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/) by Harold Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman. There's a series of video lectures to accompany the book on [MIT Open Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/).

Comment: If you're interested in other posts I have on the topic, you can query my answers for ["data abstraction"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20data%20abstraction). Another query for ["tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20tree) contains other useful examples. If you have any questions, I'm here to help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your data is the same basic shape, I would concat it as soon as possible.  You can use array destructuring in the reduce arguments (`[item]` instead of `item`) to effectively flatten it, remove duplicates with the reduce and finally sort.

```js
const data1 = [
 [{age: 23, name: "john"}],
 [{age: 24, name: "jane"}],
 [{age: 25, name: "sam"}],
 [{age: 26, name: "smith"}]
];

const data2 = [
 [{age: 23, name: "bob"}],
 [{age: 24, name: "billy"}],
 [{age: 25, name: "sam"}],
 [{age: 26, name: "brenda"}]
];

const result = data1.concat(data2)
  .reduce((acc, [item], i, arr) => {
    if (!acc[item.name]) acc[item.name] = item;
    if (i === arr.length - 1) return Object.values(acc);
    return acc;
  }, {})
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the your algorithm's complexity lives on "how to understand uniqueness" as your data seems to have no primary keys (e.g. `id`s).

In my example,
an element is unique by `age` and `name`.

Perhaps you might want a different technique.

Sorting and Mapping is then easy enough :)

```js
const toHash = ({ age, name }) => `${age}_${name}`.toUpperCase();

const fn = R.pipe(
  R.concat,
  R.flatten,
  
  // Remove Duplicates
  R.indexBy(toHash),
  R.values,

  // sort
  R.sortBy(R.prop('age')),
);

const a = [
  [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
  [{age: 24, name: 'jane'}],
  [{age: 25, name: 'sam'}],
  [{age: 26, name: 'smith'}],
  [{age: 30, name: 'paul'}],
];

const b = [
  [{age: 27, name: 'mike'}],
  [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
  [{age: 28, name: 'joanne'}],
  [{age: 29, name: 'lois'}],
  [{age: 30, name: 'paul'}],
];

console.log(
  fn(a, b),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const source1 = [
    [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
    [{age: 24, name: 'jane'}],
    [{age: 25, name: 'sam'}],
    [{age: 26, name: 'smith'}]
  ];
  
  const source2 = [
    [{age: 23, name: 'john'}],
    [{age: 24, name: 'jane'}],
    [{age: 25, name: 'sam'}],
    [{age: 26, name: 'smith'}],
    [{age: 27, name: 'mike'}],
    [{age: 28, name: 'joanne'}],
    [{age: 29, name: 'lois'}],
    [{age: 30, name: 'paul'}]
  ];
  
 
let source  = [...source1,...source2].flat().reduce((initialState,currentObject)=>{
let [newSource,hashMap]=initialState
if( hashMap[currentObject.age] === undefined){
    hashMap[currentObject.age] = currentObject.name
    newSource.push(currentObject)
} 
return initialState
},[[],{}])[0]
  console.log({ source});
```

This pretty much has an O(n+m). the two spread operator has the complexity of O(n+m) before adding them into an array.  function. also when trying to check for an element, it is always good to use hashMap or an object, this approach results in a time complexity of O(1) when searching instead of using array.includes which has the worst case of O(N). I know this solution is coming late but I hope it benefits everyone. less I forget the time complexity of the script is O(N * M) + O(N * M) + O(N * M)  = 3 O(N * M) which is still O(N * M).
The first O(N * M) is for the spread operator
The second O(N * M) is for the flat function
the third is for the reduced function
Thanks all.