# Nodejs: Object aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am using Nodejs & would like to group my object array based on few attributes.
example `attr_id` & `type` will be unique

```
const normalizedList =[ {
        "attr_id": 1,
        "type": "color",
        "value_index": 10,
        "value_label": "Blue"
    },
    {
        "attr_id": 1,
        "type": "color",
        "value_index": 15,
        "value_label": "Red"
    },
    {
        "attr_id": 2,
        "type": "size",
        "value_index": 10,
        "value_label": "Small"
    },
    {
        "attr_id": 2,
        "type": "size",
        "value_index": 14,
        "value_label": "Big"
    }
];
```

Needs to be converted to

```
[{
        "attr_id": 1,
        "type": "color",
        "values": [{
                "index": 10,
                "label": "Blue"
            }, {
                "index": 15,
                "label": "Red"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "attr_id": 2,
        "type": "size",
        "values": [{
                "index": 10,
                "label": "Small"
            }, {
                "index": 14,
                "label": "Big"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I was trying to do this without any packages like "underscore" or "json-aggregate". as not many places in the code we do any grouping/aggregation

Below is how I was able to solve

```
const groupJson = (arr,g_label) =>{
// group the list by 'attr_id'
    const groupedAttrList = normalizedList.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
      let key = obj[g_label]
      if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = []
      }
      acc[key].push(obj)
      return acc
    },{});
    const finalArray = [];

  // Now iterate over the groupedAttrList 
    for (let typeRow in groupedAttrList){
      let resultObj = {};
      let tempRow = groupedAttrList[typeRow];
      // as attr_id,type are unique for the set; picking it from 1st
      const {attr_id,type} = tempRow [0];
      resultObj .attr_id= attr_id;
      resultObj .type= type;
      // get all the values
      resultObj .values = tempRow .map(v=>{
        return {index:v.value_index,label:v.value_label};
      });
      finalArray.push(resultObj );
    }
    console.log(finalArray);
};
```

Test

```
let tempResult = groupJson(normalizedList,'attr_id');
```

wanted to learn if there are better ways to do it

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: This better fits the Code Review.

Comment: Appreciate if someone improves the code

Comment: compound data equality is a tough nut to crack in javascript. i think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67142812/633183) to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess you can make it more dynamic(something to group by an unknown amount of attributes)

First, I give you the answer in your output format in structure
`[{values:[...objectsInGroup],...groupingInfo}, ...otherGroupObjects]`

```js
const myList=[{"attr_id":1,"type":"color","value_index":10,"value_label":"Blue"},{"attr_id":1,"type":"color","value_index":15,"value_label":"Red"},{"attr_id":2,"type":"size","value_index":10,"value_label":"Small"},{"attr_id":2,"type":"size","value_index":14,"value_label":"Big"}]
function groupList(list,attributes){
  var cache={} //for finding elements that have the same attributes
  for(let item of list){
    let ID=attributes.map(attr=>item[attr]).join('-')
    //items with same ID would be grouped together
    cache[ID]? cache[ID].values.push(item): cache[ID]={values:[item]}
    //if ID exists.. add to the group, else make the group
    attributes.forEach(key=>{
      if(!cache[ID][key]){ cache[ID][key]=item[key] }
    })
  }
  return Object.values(cache)
}

const newList=groupList(myList,['attr_id','type'])
console.log(newList)
```

But what if there was a `values` attribute that is in the original `item`s in the `list` that you wanted it sorted by? only one value can exist per key.. in that case you can change the structure to
`[{values:[...objectsInGroup],info:{...groupingInfo}} ...otherGroupObjects]`

```js
const myList=[{"attr_id":1,"type":"color","value_index":10,"value_label":"Blue"},{"attr_id":1,"type":"color","value_index":15,"value_label":"Red"},{"attr_id":2,"type":"size","value_index":10,"value_label":"Small"},{"attr_id":2,"type":"size","value_index":14,"value_label":"Big"}]
function groupList(list,attributes){
  var cache={} //for finding elements that have the same attributes
  for(let item of list){
    let ID=attributes.map(attr=>item[attr]).join('-')
    //items with same ID would be grouped together
    cache[ID]? cache[ID].values.push(item): cache[ID]={values:[item]}
    //if ID exists.. add to the group, else make the group
    if(!cache[ID].info){
      cache[ID].info={} //info about the grouping of this array
      attributes.forEach(key=>cache[ID].info[key]=item[key])
    }
  }
  return Object.values(cache)
}

const newList=groupList(myList,['attr_id','type'])
console.log(newList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, i liked the first one

Answer (score 1):

Im not necessarily sure if this is any better, but this is how I would maybe go about this. You could easily wrap this into a function

```
const finalObjects = [];
const checkIdInArray = (id) => finalObjects.find((obj) => obj.attr_id === id);

normalizedList.forEach((element) => {
  if (!checkIdInArray(element.attr_id)) {
    // Then add to array as its not been added yet
    finalObjects.push({
      attr_id: element.attr_id,
      type: element.type,
      values: [
        {
          index: element.value_index,
          label: element.value_label,
        },
      ],
    });
    return;
  }
  // Get the index of the existing id
  const arrIndex = finalObjects.findIndex((e) => e.attr_id === element.attr_id);
  finalObjects[arrIndex].values.push({
    index: element.value_index,
    label: element.value_label,
  });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalObjects));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solution is simple & easy to understand